# Add a date updated/date modified option using custom fields

Tags: customization, custom-field, post-meta, seo

I run a news website, and I think there are considerable benefits to adding a last date updated option to it. However, everything I see online is for replacing the published date with the date modified. I want both, like [in this article by the NYT](https://www.nytimes.com/2020/04/03/world/europe/coronavirus-language-confusion.html).

What's more, I don't want this on every article since I edit articles a lot and don't always want each of them to reflect it. Instead, I want it for "evergreen" content that has proven popular long after it was published; my hope is that Google shows the more recent time in search results. As a result, I prefer doing this with a custom field or a CF plugin -- I currently have CMB2 installed.

The not-very-helpful theme I use uses the below function to add dates to posts:

```
if (!function_exists('mh_magazine_post_meta')) {
    function mh_magazine_post_meta() {
        $mh_magazine_options = mh_magazine_theme_options();
        if ($mh_magazine_options['post_meta_date'] === 'enable' || $mh_magazine_options['post_meta_author'] === 'enable' && in_the_loop() || $mh_magazine_options['post_meta_cat'] === 'enable' && in_the_loop() && is_singular() || $mh_magazine_options['post_meta_comments'] === 'enable') {
            echo '<div class="mh-meta entry-meta">' . "\n";
                if ($mh_magazine_options['post_meta_date'] === 'enable') {
                    echo '<span class="entry-meta-date updated"><i class="fa fa-clock-o"></i><a href="' . esc_url(get_month_link(get_the_time('Y'), get_the_time('m'))) . '">' . get_the_date() . '</a></span>' . "\n";
                }
                if ($mh_magazine_options['post_meta_author'] === 'enable' && in_the_loop()) {
                    echo '<span class="entry-meta-author author vcard"><i class="fa fa-user"></i><a class="fn" href="' . esc_url(get_author_posts_url(get_the_author_meta('ID'))) . '">' . esc_html(get_the_author()) . '</a></span>' . "\n";
                }
                if ($mh_magazine_options['post_meta_cat'] === 'enable' && in_the_loop() && is_singular()) {
                    echo '<span class="entry-meta-categories"><i class="fa fa-folder-open-o"></i>' . get_the_category_list(', ', '') . '</span>' . "\n";
                }
                if ($mh_magazine_options['post_meta_comments'] === 'enable') {
                    echo '<span class="entry-meta-comments"><i class="fa fa-comment-o"></i>';
                        mh_magazine_comment_count();
                    echo '</span>' . "\n";
                }
            echo '</div>' . "\n";
        }
    }
}
add_action('mh_post_header', 'mh_magazine_post_meta');
```

How do I do this? I don't like installing plugins, so I am thinking of something I can add myself and call through a custom field.

Comment: WP already has a date modified field in the posts table! Also just because a post has a modified date, doesn't mean you have to display it.

Comment: When you say in the posts table, where exactly do you mean? I know it shows modified dates, and I can see this in the source code -- probably because I enabled the option in my SEO plugin. About displaying it, I made it clear in my original post that I want to enable it for certain posts, not all. That is why I am asking for a custom field option.

Answer (score 0):

### **Adding a custom field to conditionally display last modified date:**

You can use the built-in custom fields metabox of your post. Usually it is hidden by default, so you have to enable it going to 'Screen Options ' and checking the 'Custom Fields' box like this:

[image]

If you're using the new block editor, you'll find the option by going to the **Edit Post Screen** > **Click the three dots button on the top right corner** > **Settings** > **Advanced Panels**.

Now, add a new custom field, let's call it `show_last_modified` and set it to true.

[image]

### **Displaying the last modified date:**

The function [`the_modified_date()`](https://developer.wordpress.org/reference/functions/the_modified_date/) will give you the date on which the post was last modified.

To display it, seems that you will have to override the `mh_magazine_post_meta()` function.

```
function mh_magazine_post_meta() {
    $mh_magazine_options = mh_magazine_theme_options();
    if ($mh_magazine_options['post_meta_date'] === 'enable' || $mh_magazine_options['post_meta_author'] === 'enable' && in_the_loop() || $mh_magazine_options['post_meta_cat'] === 'enable' && in_the_loop() && is_singular() || $mh_magazine_options['post_meta_comments'] === 'enable') {
        echo '<div class="mh-meta entry-meta">' . "\n";
            if ($mh_magazine_options['post_meta_date'] === 'enable') {
                echo '<span class="entry-meta-date updated"><i class="fa fa-clock-o"></i><a href="' . esc_url(get_month_link(get_the_time('Y'), get_the_time('m'))) . '">' . get_the_date() . '</a></span>' . "\n";
                // Custom code

                if(!empty(get_post_meta(get_the_ID(), 'show_last_modified', true)){
                   echo 'Last modified date:' . the_modified_date();
                }

                //
            }
            if ($mh_magazine_options['post_meta_author'] === 'enable' && in_the_loop()) {
                echo '<span class="entry-meta-author author vcard"><i class="fa fa-user"></i><a class="fn" href="' . esc_url(get_author_posts_url(get_the_author_meta('ID'))) . '">' . esc_html(get_the_author()) . '</a></span>' . "\n";
            }
            if ($mh_magazine_options['post_meta_cat'] === 'enable' && in_the_loop() && is_singular()) {
                echo '<span class="entry-meta-categories"><i class="fa fa-folder-open-o"></i>' . get_the_category_list(', ', '') . '</span>' . "\n";
            }
            if ($mh_magazine_options['post_meta_comments'] === 'enable') {
                echo '<span class="entry-meta-comments"><i class="fa fa-comment-o"></i>';
                    mh_magazine_comment_count();
                echo '</span>' . "\n";
            }
        echo '</div>' . "\n";
    }
}

add_action('mh_post_header', 'mh_magazine_post_meta');
```

Place the above code on your child theme and customize the markup to suit your needs.

Comment: Thanks. I've tried it, but there's no change. The date stays the same.

Comment: Where did you add the code?

Comment: Child theme, in a custom functions plugin.

Comment: If you remove the original function and leave only the new one on the child theme, does it get displayed?